# Como aplicar o código do SliverAppBar class no Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Encontrei na documentação do Flutter o **SliverAppBar**. Porém, como estou inciando com Flutter, tenho dúvidas de como e onde inserir o código dentro do meu projeto em Flutter. Devo criar uma classe específica pra ele, ou devo inserir dentro do "*main.dart*"?
Agradeço.

Comment: Em Flutter você pode programar tudo em um só arquivo, criar tudo em uma única estrutura... Mas seguindo as boas práticas, é bom você criar uma classe a parte, com sua `SliveAppBar` e depois fazer a chamada dela onde precisar, seja no *main.dart* ou em outra tela... Te aconselho dar uma olhadinha nessas duas playlist [Flutter Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3FZoDmO7OY&list=PLHAtJbrQ17AVYeC8-CAKDCy2fYPFSGtd0) e nessa outra [Pokedex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xUsD0XRa04&list=PLHAtJbrQ17AVj0LJEc955109XpX925Pt1)

Comment: Com esses duas playlists você vai consegui entender bem o início em Flutter

Comment: Beleza. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    /* **************
                 * START***
************** */

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Sliver app bars are typically used as the first child of a CustomScrollView, which lets the app bar integrate
/// with the scroll view so that it can vary in height according to the scroll offset or float above the other
/// content in the scroll view.
class LSliverAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 250.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('Demo Appbar'),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 50.0,
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                  child: Text('List Item $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/* **************
***************
***************
              * END***
***************
***************
************** */
```